# How do I automatically change from dark to light themes and back again in VS CODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the morning, light comes out of the window and the monitor reflects it and prevents me from working with a dark theme. In the evening, in the dark, the light theme makes my eyes ache. I have to constantly switch back and forth.

Is there any way that Visual Studio Code automatically uses a light theme in the morning and a dark theme in the evening?

Answer (score 10):

Make it follow your OS theme. First option under "window" in VSCode settings -

[image]
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_auto-switch-based-on-os-color-scheme

`window.autoDetectColorScheme`

Then, just let your OS do the day/night switching. On mac os this can be done by setting the theme to "Auto".
[image]

Similar option probably exists on windows too.

Answer (score 4):

It won't do it automatically but it will make it easier: there will be in vscode v1.69 a command to toggle between light and dark themes:

```
Preferences: Toggle between Light/Dark Themes
workbench.action.toggleLightDarkThemes
```

The command is unbound but you can make a keybinding if you wish from the Keyboard Shortcuts editor or in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+h",
  "command": "workbench.action.toggleLightDarkThemes"
}
```

It toggles between your settings `Workbench: Preferred Light Color Theme` and `Workbench: Preferred Dark Color Theme` - so change those settings to match your preferred color themes.

Comment: Auto switch based on OS color scheme. Windows and macOS support light and dark color schemes. A setting, `window.autoDetectColorScheme`, instructs VS Code to listen to changes to the OS's color scheme and switch to a matching theme accordingly. To customize the themes used when a color scheme changes, you can set the preferred light, dark, and high-contrast themes with the settings.